Vis.js Adds Extra Padding at the Top of a Complex Diagram
I've been working with vis.js to create a complex diagram, and I've encountered an issue that persists even in a simplified version of my project. The core of the problem is that, when I draw a large diagram, it seems to automatically add extra padding at the top, effectively pushing the diagram down.
This issue becomes more pronounced as the size of the diagram increases. For example, with var number_of_nodes = 100, the diagram gets pushed down by approximately half of the screen's height. However, with var number_of_nodes = 10, the extra padding is much less noticeable.
    var xScale = 1;
    var yScale = 10;
    var number_of_nodes = 100.    // This is the value makes the issue visible. But less visible when using 10 
    var graph = new Graph(document.getElementById('mynetwork'), xScale, yScale, theme, number_of_nodes);

To reproduce the issue, you'll need to set number_of_nodes to 100. I've created a complete example on jsfiddle, which can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/master_chief/zy1Lfx2q/. Note: The number_of_nodes value needs to be updated to 100 in the example to observe the issue as described.
I have attempted step-by-step debugging but haven't been able to identify the cause of this unwanted padding. Does anyone see any obvious mistakes in my code, or has anyone encountered a similar issue and found a solution?

I added the line: console.log(Node ID: ${visNode.id}, Label: ${visNode.label}, x: ${visNode.x}, y: ${visNode.y});
According to that the first box should been drawn at y = 0. I think it might be a bug in visjs when you take control over the drawing your self. I see most of the examples let vis do the drawing on https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/
But since you have taken control over it I assume you need that and can´t let the vis do the drawing is that correct?
